# Change in a Fortran array results in change of another when using C pointers

Tags: arrays, fortran, fftw

I have C-type SIMD allocations using FFTW3 of two arrays `f` and `g` using the same plans. I have simply set `f` to `1`, then `g` to `f`, then zeroed `f`. This also ends up zeroing `g`.

Why does this arise and what are some ways I can ensure that any derived arrays by slicing for example, don't get modified.

I would like `f` and `g` to point to two different blocks of two-dimensioanl double precision memory. I have not used the usual explicit shape (`double precision, dimension(n,n)`) definitions as the [FFTW3 documentation](http://fftw.org/doc/Allocating-aligned-memory-in-Fortran.html#Allocating-aligned-memory-in-Fortran) states that arrays allocated in this manner are faster to deal with.

```
program main

use,intrinsic::iso_c_binding
implicit none
include 'fftw3.f03'

integer,parameter::n=16
real(C_DOUBLE),pointer::f(:,:),g(:,:)
type(C_PTR)::p

p=fftw_alloc_real(int(n**2,C_SIZE_T))
!i am thinking of these as FFTW plans that store only the stencil to
!allocate space starting from addresses given by real(C_DOUBLE),pointers above.

call c_f_pointer(p,f,[n,n])
call c_f_pointer(p,g,[n,n])

f=1.0d0
print*,sum(f)
g=f

f=0.0d0
print*,sum(g)

call fftw_free(p)
end program
```

The output is

```
256.00000000000000     
0.0000000000000000
```

Comment: You have set `f` and `g` to point to the same thing.  Do you understand the effects of that (ie., how pointers in Fortran work)?

Comment: Does the use of the same plan p do this? I have used the array declaration statements ALLOCATABLE,DIMENSION() within fortran always. I do have a general knowledge of pointers but not specific to Fortran.

Comment: Typo in `call c_f_pointer(p,g,[n,n])`?

Comment: `c_f_pointer` does nothing special (ie., it knows nothing about FFTW plans).  The two calls just point `f` and `g` (in this case) to the same target as the C pointer `p`.

Comment: @francescalus That was what I meant shouldn't the second call be: `call c_f_pointer(q,g,[n,n])`?

Comment: So the type(C_PTR) are the different memories addresses that I should be using for f and g, and real,pointer f and g are just labels/handles to access these?

Comment: @francescalus you are right about the '[n,n]' part, indicates not to a 'p' 'q' typo (but maybe even more...)

Comment: Could you clarify, in the question (as an [edit]) what you want to happen?  That is, how you intend to use the various memory aspects/pointers.  As it is, we're probably guessing about what you mean by re-using FFTW plans (consider also the next reader with the same problem who isn't using FFTW but something else).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The allocation of memory is done by `fftw_alloc_real`.  You call that only once, so only one block of memory is allocated.  `c_f_pointer` does not perform any allocation.

`c_f_pointer` takes a C pointer and pointer associates a Fortran pointer with the target of the C pointer.  When you

```
call c_f_pointer(p,f,[n,n])
call c_f_pointer(p,g,[n,n])
```

you are associating both `f` and `g` with the same lump of memory, that pointed to by `p`.

Simply allocate two distinct parts, with two calls to `fftw_alloc_real` and point `f` to one and `g` to the other.